# Import and use client provided .cer certificate in api callout

Tags: webservices, certificates

This may be a common issue that many of us have faced but unfortunately not getting concrete answer on any of the blogs/forums. 
I want to use client provided external .cer certificate in making API call. I came to know that We cannot import .cer certificates using salesforce keystore.

Previously, this could be achieved by uploading .cer file to static resource and then while making api call converting it to base 64 and using in setClientCertificate() method. But now this method is deprecated.

Need help on how to achieve the goal now?